# cascading style sheets floats

Tags: css, html, css-float

in the code below, i would like to align the text in the content div, the one in the right, to beging close to the border, not far from the navigation menu 
i know this is due to my nav menu floated left, but i can't make it !!!!!

```
                <div style="position:relative; top:10px; float:left; border: 1px blue dashed; width:150px">
                <ul>
                    <li style="margin-top:2px; padding-bottom:15px; list-style-type:none"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li style="margin-top:2px; padding-bottom:15px; list-style-type:none"><a href="Listings.html">Listings</a></li>
                    <li style="margin-top:2px; padding-bottom:15px; list-style-type:none"><a href="Financing.html">Financing</a></li>
                    <li style="margin-top:2px; padding-bottom:15px; list-style-type:none"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div style="position:relative; top:10px; border: 1px red dashed; left:155px; width:800px; min-height:600px">
                test
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Khanh Tran mentioned, you can remove the "left: 155px;" from your content div but that will affect where your border falls.  What you can then do is float that same div to the left as well.

So, change this:

```
<div style="position:relative; top:10px; border: 1px red dashed; left:155px; width:800px; min-height:600px">test</div>
```

To this:

```
<div style="float:left; position:relative; top:10px; border: 1px red dashed; width:800px; min-height:600px">test</div>
```

Comment: i cqn clear the content to clear:both or right, but then the content will start vertically after where the menu start

Comment: You won't want to apply a "clear" to the menu because it will cause the problem you mentioned.  Just remove the "left" declaration and add a "float: left" to the content div and you should be where you want to be.  If you'll be adding a footer that you want to go below it all, THEN use a "clear: both"

Answer (score 1):

Reduce `left:155px` to `left:10px` or you can completely remove this attribute.

**Update:**

you just need to set `position:absolute`

check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/2dcPE/7/

Comment: i would like the nav menu to appear outside the content, just as if you display my code but with text close to border

Comment: I'd avoid the "position: absolute" method.  In the event the OP wants to add a footer or more elements down the road, it will create all sorts of issues.  In a situation like this, I'd leave it relatively positioned and then just apply a "clear: both" to any subsequent footer elements or things that should fall below the natural flow of the content div.

Comment: Thanks Mike for your explanation. I learned it from you :) +1 for Mike

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div style="float:left; top:10px; border: 1px red dashed; width:800px; min-height:600px">
            test
        </div>​
```